# Can I trick a website into believing it always has focus?

Tags: google-chrome, focus, tampermonkey

A bit of a general question here. I want to navigate to another tab or window but I also want a particular website open in a tab to believe that it retains focus when I do that. Is there any script that I could run, maybe using TamperMonkey?
I tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/661013) but it didn't work for the website I needed it to. The website in question pops up a warning every time focus is lost.

Comment: You can override EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener to lie about `blur` event, document.hasFocus, and other functions of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this to always return true when the website checks for focus:

```js
document.hasFocus = function (){ return true }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: document.hasFocus = true;